#  Stieltjes Constant limit

Tags: nt.number-theory

what is the limit :

$\lim_{n->\infty} \frac{\gamma_{n-1}}{\gamma_{n}}$

$\gamma_{n}$ being the [nth Stieltjes Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StieltjesConstants.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An asymptotic formula for $\gamma_n$ is given here:

http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2011-80-273/S0025-5718-2010-02390-7/S0025-5718-2010-02390-7.pdf

From that formula, it is perhaps possible to find at least some estimates for the limit you ask about.

Comment: That points to something behind a paywall - could you point us to something accessible?

Comment: Strangely enough, I could read the paper from my home computer. I have just emailed it to you.

Comment: Perhaps it is possible/not too much work to reflect some of the relevant formula here (I too cannot access the article)

Comment: Here is another link: http://indigo.lib.uic.edu:8080/dspace/bitstream/10027/7712/1/S0025-5718-2010-02390-7.pdf